# How to remove get the 500 error from the php contact form?

Tags: php, forms, email, syntax-error, contact-form

I am new to PHP and I am getting some problems with my PHP form. Can anyone help me?

When I try to submit the detail I get:

> Error: 500 Internal Server Error.

> PHP Fatal error: The allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted.

I already tried several methods but can't figure out what to do.

```
 <div class="form">
          <form action="./assets/vendor/php-email-form/php-email-form.php" method="post" role="form"
            class="php-email-form">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-6 mt-3 mt-lg-0">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="my-3">
              <div class="loading">Loading</div>
              <div class="error-message"></div>
              <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" title="Send Message">Send Message</button></div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

And here the PHP file:

```
<?php
  /**
  * Requires the "PHP Email Form" library
  * The "PHP Email Form" library is available only in the pro version of the template
  * The library should be uploaded to: vendor/php-email-form/php-email-form.php
  * For more info and help: https://bootstrapmade.com/php-email-form/
  */

  // Replace contact@example.com with your real receiving email address
  $receiving_email_address = 'techruptinnovations@gmail.com';

  if( file_exists($php_email_form = '../../../assets/vendor/php-email-form/php-email-form.php' )) {
    include( $php_email_form );
  } else {
    die( 'Unable to load the "PHP Email Form" Library!');
  }

  $contact = new PHP_Email_Form;
  $contact->ajax = true;

  $contact->to = $receiving_email_address;
  $contact->from_name = $_POST['name'];
  $contact->from_email = $_POST['email'];
  $contact->subject = $_POST['subject'];

  // Uncomment below code if you want to use SMTP to send emails. You need to enter your correct SMTP credentials
  /*
  $contact->smtp = array(
    'host' => 'example.com',
    'username' => 'example',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'port' => '587'
  );
  */

  $contact->add_message( $_POST['name'], 'From');
  $contact->add_message( $_POST['email'], 'Email');
  $contact->add_message( $_POST['message'], 'Message', 10);

  echo $contact->send();
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? More than 500 MB for a single contact form looks like a lot

Comment: My guess is that you have some sort of never finishing loop wich will fill the memory until the limit is reached. Could it be that your .php file is '../../../assets/vendor/php-email-form/php-email-form.php' itself? So you have an include-loop?

Comment: Certainly need to see the content of php-email-form.php